# Highlight Background of selected slot in react-big-calendar even after finished selecting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-big-calendar

Now the default behavior is whenever someone select a slot it highlights in gray, but as soon as the selection stops the calendar fields highlighting vanishes. If we open modal on selection than it will not be that necessary, but in my case 70% width is of calendar and 30% is the form. So when the selection is made than the dates update in the form but there is nothing remains highlighted, so it create confusion.

fullcalendar has a option "unselectAuto" which default to true.

react-big-calandar has not implemented this yet and open to a PR. Is there any solution/hack around this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I did this using the `slotPropGetter` and tracking `selected`

```js
  // This handles styling the 'selected' slot background in the Scheduler
  const slotPropGetter = (slotDate) => {
    if (
      selected &&
      !selected.IsAllDayAppointment &&
      moment(slotDate).isBetween(
        moment(selected.StartDateTime).subtract(1, 'm').toJSON(),
        selected.EndDateTime
      )
    ) {
      return {
        style: { backgroundColor: '#999', borderTop: '1px solid #999' },
      };
    }
  };
```

My date implementation is a little different, but ultimately it's just checking that the `slotDate` is between my `selected` value's `start` and `end`. Using the `slotPropGetter` you can apply either custom `style`s or `class`es to the slot, [according to the documentation](http://jquense.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html#prop-slotPropGetter).